# Make one page not route

Tags: .htaccess

I am attempting to create a sitemap for my website, that has been uploaded to the website. Whenever I attempt to access it, the `.htaccess` redirects me to the `index.php`, which means websites that need use my sitemap gets an error, as it only gets to see the site’s index page.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The above is my `.htaccess`. How would I go about not redirecting a certain page, such as `sitemap.xml`?

As of now, I have attempted to get more aquainted with `.htaccess`, yet I require a whole lot more of the good old learning process. Once I have solved this, at least I will not have to ask any more questions about `.htaccess`, as I am learning it at this very moment.

Comment: You have two conditions for `!-d` when usually there would be `!-d !-l !-f` the `f` meaning "don't apply this rewrite to real files that exist.  I'm guessing there's a typo there and you ought to replace one `!-d` with `!-f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> ```

The last *CondPattern* should be `!-f` to prevent files from being rewritten. The first two are for directories and symbolic links respectively.